# Zend Form from simple html

Tags: php, html, zend-framework, zend-form

My task is to create a Zend Form from the next Html:

```
<form method="post">
   <h3><a href="">link1</a></h3>
   <div>
      <input type="text" name="name1">
   </div>
   <h3><a href="">link2</a></h3>
   <div>
      <input type="text" name="name2">
   </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the very least you'll have to remove `DtDd` Decorator, set the `Html` Decorator tag to div and remove the `Label` Decorator.

I suggest you make the form as best you can then work from that, at least give it a go.

In the worst situation you will have to write your own form elements to replicate this HTML.